# Calling Robot Framework files from within Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotframework

Have been in a bind over the weekend.

I am attempting to create a Python Application that will give users the ability to run .Robot files (or Test Cases) (from within Python)

I am attempting to run these files through the use of the 'subprocess' module, but I continually receive the following error message :

> 'FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
>   specified'

I have included 'import subprocess'

I have also declared the location of the .Robot Test Case as a variable:

```
Location = r'C:/Users/verti/PycharmProjects/ChristSax.com/ChristSaxTestSuite/PageSmokeTest.Robot'
```

Within my code, I've attempted to call the Robotframework file with the following statement :

```
def AutomatedSmokePage():
    print("Automated Page Smoke Tests now running...")
    subprocess.call(['pybot',Location])
```

I am currently using Python 3.6.1 and Robot Framework version 3.0.2

Any help would be appreciated. If you know of a better means to accomplish the same task, please let me know.

Comment: I would start by calling Robot not by pybot but rather as "python -m robot.run" command, than try to concatenate  robot call with Location as one string.

Comment: Thanks for the example, if it's not too much trouble, can you provide a brief example of how this can be done?

Comment: what happens if you just open a shell/cmd and enter `pybot C:/Users/verti/PycharmProjects/ChristSax.com/ChristSaxTestSuite/PageSmokeTest.Robot`

Comment: @Verv: When I type the location into Command Prompt and click 'Enter', the .Robot Test Case begins to run. If I copy the location into Command Prompt, spaces will be displayed within Suite & Robot (i.e. ChristSaxTestSu ite, PageSmokeTest.Ro bot)

Comment: I'm still a little confused as to why the same location variable works with certain commands and not others. I've found the following also works for me:  ``os.chdir("C:/Users//verti/PycharmProjects/ChristSax.com/Chr‌​istSaxTestSuite/")`` ``os.system('pybot -N PageSmokeTest -r ' 'AutomatedSmokeTest.html -l AutomatedSmokeTest.html -o ' 'AutomatedSmokeTest.xml AutomatedSmokeTest.robot')``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets assume that you are on windows platform  and your robot file which you want t o run is in some other directory

you can use subprocess module to do the task for you like mentioned below

```
from subprocess import Popen 
from subprocess import Popen, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,PIPE,STDOUT
import platform 
class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def run_robotfiles(self,terminal,command1):
        if platform.system()=='Windows':
            self.terminal=terminal
            self.command1=command1
            self.command_server1=self.terminal+' '+self.command1
            self.server1_start=Popen(self.command_server1,creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)

abc=Server()
#you can give path till the robot file or you can use a batch file
#K option tells cmd to run the command and keep the command window from closing. You may use /C instead to close the command window after the command finishes.
abc.run_robotfiles('cmd','/K pybot D:\Users\process.robot')
```

Answer (score 2):

My generic method for running external command from python scripts with stdout output:

```
import sys
import subprocess

def run_process(command):
    print("Running command: " + command)
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    while True:
        if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
            nextline = str(p.stdout.readline(),"utf-8")
        else:
            nextline = p.stdout.readline()
        if nextline == '' and p.poll() is not None:
            break
        sys.stdout.write(nextline)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

I still don't know what happens when you try to run @Verv command (maybe pybot is not accessible in command prompt), so I would suggest try following:

```
python_path = 'c:/Python36/python.exe -m robot.run'
Location ='C:/Users/verti/PycharmProjects/ChristSax.com/ChristSaxTestSuite/PageSmokeTest.Robot'
command=python_path+' '+Location
run_process(command)
```

Check the output which may indicate what is wrong (tested locally).

Comment: Unfortunately, when I use the above code, here is the error message I receive : The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: try to limit "command" part to debug why system cannot find specified path - start with command=' c:/Python36/python.exe --version' , later on command=' c:/Python36/python.exe -m robot.libdoc --help'. There must be some small,silly issue which is hidden in plain sight.