# How to get the result of a ran Robot file using popen?

Tags: python, robotframework

I want to be able to retrieve the result (whether it passed or it failed) of the robot test that is ran using popen. I want to use popen to support dialog boxes and tests that are not dialog boxes. Is there any way to retrieve the result? I am using the code from this page here [(link).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47392772/calling-robot-framework-files-from-within-python/47408239#47408239)

```
import sys
import subprocess

my_path = sys.executable
def run_process(command):
    print("Running command: " + command)
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    while True:
        if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
            nextline = str(p.stdout.readline(),"utf-8")
        else:
            nextline = p.stdout.readline()
        if nextline == '' and p.poll() is not None:
            break
        sys.stdout.write(nextline)
        sys.stdout.flush()

python_path = my_path + ' -m robot.run'
Location ='C:/Users/Desktop/pass_or_fail.robot'
command=python_path+' '+Location
run_process(command)
print(my_path)
```

Comment: Can you highlight what is not working for you? I.e. what’s the error you’re facing?

Answer (score 0):

If the tests passes or fails it can be stored as an integer. For example, a 0 represents that the test passed and anything greater than 0 represents that the test failed. That's why I used:

`output = p.communicate()[0] 
 rc = p.returncode`

```
import sys
import subprocess

my_path = sys.executable
def run_process(command):
    global output
    global rc
    print("Running command: " + command)
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    while True:
        if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
            nextline = str(p.stdout.readline(),"utf-8")
        else:
            nextline = p.stdout.readline()
        if nextline == '' and p.poll() is not None:
            break
        sys.stdout.write(nextline)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        output = p.communicate()[0]
        rc = p.returncode
python_path = my_path + ' -m robot.run'
Location ='C:/Users/Desktop/pass_or_fail.robot'
command=python_path+' '+Location
run_process(command)
print(my_path)
print(rc)
```

Comment: The return code is the number of failed cases - 0 means zero failed, X - that X failed. If your suite had a single case, that may have mislead you into thinking the RC is either 0 or 1. There's some [more info in the user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#return-codes).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `popen` I would suggest the usage of the `robot.run.run_cli(arguments=None, exit=True)` [Robot Framework API function](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/v3.2.2/autodoc/robot.html?highlight=run_cli#robot.run.run_cli).

> ```python
> from robot import run_cli
>
> # Run tests and return the return code.
> rc = run_cli(['--name', 'Example', 'tests.robot'], exit=False)
> ```

This would simplify the execution while having the same return codes.

> A return code is returned similarly as when running on the command
> line. Zero means that tests were executed and no critical test failed,
> values up to 250 denote the number of failed critical tests, and
> values between 251-255 are for other statuses documented in the [Robot Framework User Guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#return-codes).

Furthermore with multiple runs executed programmatically the `robot.rebot.rebot_cli(arguments=None, exit=True)` [API call](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/v3.2.2/autodoc/robot.html?highlight=run_cli#robot.rebot.rebot_cli) can be used to merge all results into a single log.html and report.html file.

> ```python
> from robot import rebot_cli
>
> rebot_cli(['--name', 'Example', '--log', 'NONE', 'o1.xml', 'o2.xml'])
> ```